# VirtualBox Microphone Bug

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I'm trying to get my Windows 7 computer's built-in microphone to work inside the Genymotion Android virtualizer, but there is apparently a VirtualBox bug - https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11133 - Does anyone have a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings` and then to `Audio` and there verify the audio drivers installed and the audio controller being used by the virtual box. I think that this problem might be due to the *Driver Not Installed* issue or the host settings are not configured properly with the host machine and the virtual box.